Is there a Gradle plugin for checking binary compatibility of external libraries
Is there a Gradle plugin or another tool which will check that the implementation libraries have binary compatibility?
For example, I'm use picture-compose lib that depends from picture-load.
And bumb picture-compose from v.1.5.0 to 2.0.0. And If picture-compose has no binary compatibility with picture-load I find out about it only in runtime.
But I want to known about it on my merge request in Bitbacket.
I known about binary-compatibility-validator but it don't check external libs (https://github.com/Kotlin/binary-compatibility-validator)
